# How to remove htaccess redirect from http to https?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, browser, https

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

My goal was redirecting all http-requests to https - it works.
Now I removed the htaccess-file because I need to test something without https. Calling http://www.domain.com redirects again to https://www.domain.com.

Why? The htaccess-file was removed. I think the problem is the browser, but those settings were not saved in a cookie or something, were they?

Thx!

Comment: Test in a different browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: It´s working correctly in other browsers. But my question is why? A htaccess file isnt downloaded the the client. So after deleting the htaccess at the server, the https redirection should not work anymore.

Comment: As @anubhava said, clear your cache. You had a permanent redirect `R=301` which the browser cached, it is not even bothering to ask for the `http` version, it is requesting the `https` version directly. Nothing to do with `htaccess`